# A question about convergence of the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following series convergent?
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}.$$
Indeed, is it possible to conclude that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$  is convergent if and only if  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$  is convergent? If this is true, by the ratio test, if we assume that $a_n=(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$, then it turns out that
$$\left\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}\right\vert.$$
On the other hand, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\vert=0.$$
Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$  is convergent. Consequently, based on these considerations, the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ is convergent.

Comment: $(2n+1)!$ is not defined for $n<0$.

Comment: @ Wojowu Please see this article: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4247832/

Comment: This uses a nonstandard definition of factorials, if you are using it, please indicate that in the body of the question.

Comment: @Wojowu With this definition, is my proof stated above true?